# Entity Framework Code First - Configuration in another file

Tags: c#, configuration, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

What is the best way to separate the mapping of tables to entities using the Fluent API so that it is all in a separate class and not inline in the OnModelCreating method?

What I am doing currently:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext {
    // ...
    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Property( ... );
        // ...
    }
}
```

What i want:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext {
    // ...
    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.LoadConfiguration(SomeConfigurationBootstrapperClass);
    }
}
```

How do you do this? I am using C#.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will want to create a class that inherits from the [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class, like so:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        // Configuration goes here...
    }
}
```

Then you can load the configuration class as part of the context like so:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooConfiguration());
    }
}
```

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes?display=Print) goes into greater detail on using configuration classes.