# Defining CodeFirst (EF5) FluentAPI mappings across multiple classes/files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to define an entity per file? If I have a 100 entities do I have to define all 100 entities in a single DbContext class or can they be split up into individual classes/files and still work? I've most recently worked with Fluent nHibernate were each entity/table mapping is it's own class. Can this also be achieved in EF CodeFirst?

Comment: You can configure mapping on differents files. See this:
 [Entity Framework Code First - Configuration in another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475403/entity-framework-code-first-configuration-in-another-file)

Comment: Thanks! @AugustoPedraza It's almost what I want. It's disappointing that it does not automatically find all configuration classes. Especially in the age of dependency injection.